# How to use "fire"

Tags: verbs

Which one is correct?

> If they are sick or suffer from a bad illness, the boss must visit them and give them a guarantee that they *are not fired* under this situation.

or

> If they are sick or suffer from a bad illness, the boss must visit them and give them a guarantee that they *will not be fired* under this situation.

Thank you

Comment: It's not exactly what you're asking about, but I'd never use "under this situation" in either of those sentences (which both seem otherwise grammatical, though with slightly different implications). I'd almost always use "in this situation" instead. This might vary with dialect (I'm a native AmE speaker).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, you are right. I can use under this condition/circumstance or in this situation as well. However, you said both of two sentences are correct.

Comment: Will not be fired.

Comment: Both are kinda sucky, but the second is a hair better than the first.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some of this may be up to how the policy is implemented. It seems that if the policy is that staying home sick results in automatic termination, then the boss might provide a guarantee in real-time that they are not fired as they should be.

If the boss must execute paperwork or judge their sickness to decide if they will be fired, then the future tense seems to make more sense.

Comment: Merci. To the best of my knowledge, this is a perfect answer.

Comment: <sheepish> Could I trouble you to up-vote it or whatever one does to accept an answer?  Merci.

Comment: what do you mean? Actually, I did not understand your mean:(

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatical and both constructions are in common usage, and the difference in meaning is quite subtle (in most cases either one is valid). Simplifying the examples to make it clearer we could say:

- In this company, employees are not fired for being late.
- In this company, employees will not be fired for being late.